# How to pass an object data member to a lambda function in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, pointer-to-member

Let's say I have the following non-working code (just for illustration purposes):

```
class fruit
{
    public:

    std::string apple;
    std::string banana;
    std::String orange;
};

class grocery
{
    public:
    
    std::vector<fruit> g_items;
    std::string total_weight;   
};

std::vector<grocery> shopping; 

auto check_item = [&](std::string f_itm) -> void
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < shopping.g_items.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << shopping.g_items.at(i).f_itm << std::endl;
    }
};

check_item(apple);
check_item(banan);
check_item(orange)
```

How can I call the lambda function `check_item`, passing specific data members of the `fruit` object, since they all have the same type (`std:string`)?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to be able to call the lambda with a pointer to an `std::string` data member of `fruit`(?)  If so, change the lambda parameter type to `std::string (fruit::*f_itm)` and call it as e.g. `check_item(&fruit::apple)`.  Other than that I don't really understand the question.

Comment: And then inside of the lambda, you can use that `f_itm` pointer like this: `std::cout << shopping[i].g_items[j].*f_itm << std::endl;`

Comment: @G.M. Exactly. It has already been answered by Remy and Eduardo. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the lambda to take in a pointer-to-member, eg:

```cpp
class fruit
{
public:
    std::string apple;
    std::string banana;
    std::string orange;
};

class grocery
{
public:
    std::vector<fruit> g_items;
    std::string total_weight;   
};

std::vector<grocery> shopping; 

...

auto check_item = [&](std::string (fruit::*f_itm)) -> void
{
    for (auto &g : shopping)
    {
        for (auto &f : g.g_items) {
            std::cout << f.*f_itm << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

check_item(&fruit::apple);
check_item(&fruit::banana);
check_item(&fruit::orange);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/oFtL3E)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class fruit
{
public:

    std::string apple;
    std::string banana;
    std::string orange; //std::string, not std::String
};

class grocery
{
public:
    std::vector<fruit> g_items;
    std::string total_weight;
};

std::vector<grocery> shopping;


auto check_item = [&](std::string(fruit::* f_itm)) -> void
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < shopping.size(); ++i) //you have two, vectors, so first iterate through shopping
    {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < shopping[i].g_items.size(); ++j) //then, iterate through g_items 
            std::cout << shopping[i].g_items[i].*f_itm << std::endl; //then, print
    }
};

int main() {
    check_item(&fruit::apple); 
    check_item(&fruit::banana); //you put banan, not banana
    check_item(&fruit::orange); //remember the ;
}
```

Your original code had a couple of errors. Then, in your for loop, you have two iterate through both vectors, as the comments explain. Then, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections and for the solution. This is exactly what I need. This was just a test case, not the actual code.